# How would you get 3 month Average Volume for a stock in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I am trying to find a more efficient way to calculate the last 3 month volume for a given stock but I cant seem to find a function that would let me do. The other approach was get all volume data and add them and import it in the google sheet but it would take too long and wouldn't be as efficient. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read up on [`GOOGLEFINANCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) and [function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en&ref_topic=3105385) on dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example on how to calculate the last 3 months volume using `GOOGLEFINANCE` would be:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG","volume",TODAY()-90,TODAY())
```

This formula would display the information like this:

[image]